# Howto Add Custom Control Property in property Dialog Box

Tags: c#

I want to add property's to my custom control like above example property with descriptions!
I don't know hot to display that with GUI like above.
I want to know what attribute to use it.

```
private bool IsNum = true;
[PropertyTab("IsNumaric")]
[Browsable(true)]
[Description("TextBox only valid for numbers only"), Category("EmSoft")]   
public bool IsNumaricTextBox
{
    set
    {
         IsNum = value;
    }
}

protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);
    if (IsNum)
    {
        doStruf(e);   
    }
}

private void doStruf(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), "\\d+") && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

I want to display this as property tool box with Description

Like This in property box

IsNumaric True

Comment: Could you please share a bit more information? What type of GUI (Windows Forms, WPF)? What 'GUI like above' are you referring to?

Comment: Windows form application

Comment: Do you want this property to be visible during the design time (so that you can change its value in the designer)?

Comment: Yes i want to change that property at design time

Comment: Maciek how are you formatted my code snippet? i am new for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property requires a Getter in order to be displayed in the property grid:

```
private bool isNum = true;

[PropertyTab("IsNumaric")]
[Browsable(true)]
[Description("TextBox only valid for numbers only"), Category("EmSoft")] 
public bool IsNumaricTextBox {
  get { return isNum; }
  set { isNum = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks It works after get method implementing!!!! but i have a some miss understand... because i don't want to implement get method...but its work only after declare get method

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to achieve, you just have to decorate it with an attribute like in the sample below:

```
[PropertyTab("IsNumaric")]
[DisplayName("NumericOrNot")]
[Category("NewCategory")]
public bool IsNumaricTextBox
{
     set
     {
         IsNum = value;
     }
}
```

and to make it work you need following using:

```
using System.ComponentModel
```

If you do not specify `Category` - property will show under `Misc` category (please note, that by default properties are being shown by names, not by categories). In this example the property is going to be shown under `NewCategory` and the name of the property is going to be `NumericOrNot`.

Comment: this attribute should be used to decorate method. Could you please paste in your question what you have exactly? I thought you already had a custom control and the only thing you wanted to achieve was to have a property being displayed during the design time.

Comment: i want to some help,i cant copy my code to here.... they tell this Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: you can't write code in comments. edit your original question.

Comment: how are you format my code like before ? i cant do that now...if it is special tags used for it?

Comment: for code formatting: either use 4 spaces or pre & code tags (enclosed with angle brackets). Have a look at the SO editor's help - it should point you to the section where it is described in detail how to format code.

Comment: It works after get method implementing
public bool IsNumaricTextBox {
  get { return isNum; }